# How to fetch data from a website to a solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

So i have a website that generate five random numbers every 5 seconds.

Here's the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Car Data Simulator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p id="speed_traffic_highway" ></p>
        <p id="speed_traffic_village" ></p>
        <p id="headways_between_vehicles" ></p>
        <p id="acceleration" ></p>
        <p id="deceleration" ></p>
        <p id="overtaking_lane_changing" ></p>
        <p id="traffic_regulations" ></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="b_start" onclick="start_random();"> Start Generating Data </button>
        <button id="b_stop" onclick="stop_random();"> Stop Generating Data </button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    let myInterval;
    function start_random(){
        a = document.getElementById("speed_traffic_highway").innerHTML = "speed_traffic_highway: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200)
        b = document.getElementById("speed_traffic_village").innerHTML = "speed_traffic_village: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        c = document.getElementById("headways_between_vehicles").innerHTML = "headways_between_vehicles: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)
        d = document.getElementById("acceleration").innerHTML = "acceleration: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)
        e = document.getElementById("deceleration").innerHTML = "deceleration: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)
        f = document.getElementById("overtaking_lane_changing").innerHTML = "overtaking_lane_changing: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)
        g = document.getElementById("traffic_regulations").innerHTML = "traffic_regulations: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)

        console.log("speed_traffic_highway: " + a)
        console.log("speed_traffic_village: " + b)
        console.log("headways_between_vehicles: " + c)
        console.log("acceleration: " + d)
        console.log("deceleration: " + e)
        console.log("overtaking_lane_changing: " + f)
        console.log("traffic_regulations: " + g)
        console.log("")

        myInterval = setTimeout(start_random, 5000);
    }


    function stop_random(){
        document.getElementById("speed_traffic_highway").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("speed_traffic_village").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("headways_between_vehicles").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("acceleration").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("deceleration").innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("overtaking_lane_changing").innerHTML =""
        document.getElementById("traffic_regulations").innerHTML = ""
        clearTimeout(myInterval);
    }
</script>

<style> 

    body{
        background-color: pink;
        text-align: center;
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
        
    }

    #b_start{
        background-color: green;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        float: left;
    }

    #b_stop{
        background-color: red;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 15px;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        float: left;
    }

</style>

</html>
```

I want my smart contract to fetch data from this website every 5 seconds and to use it as a parameter for my solidity function. How can i do it?

Here's the code of my smart contract :

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol"; 

contract Premium {

    mapping(address => score) public final_score;
    struct score {
        uint256 driver_score;
        uint256 price;
    }

    function premium_Price (uint256 speed_traffic_highway, uint256 speed_traffic_village, uint256 headways_between_vehicles, uint256 acceleration, uint256 deceleration, uint256 overtaking_lane_changing , uint256 traffic_regulations) public returns (uint256, uint256){
        
        if(final_score[msg.sender].driver_score==0){
            final_score[msg.sender].driver_score=50;
        }

        if(final_score[msg.sender].driver_score>=1){
            if(60<=speed_traffic_highway || speed_traffic_highway>=120){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score--;
            }

            if(20<=speed_traffic_village || speed_traffic_village>=40){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score--;
            }

            if(headways_between_vehicles<3){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score--;
            }

            if(acceleration>6){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score--;
            }

            if(deceleration<5){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score--;
            }

            if(overtaking_lane_changing>10){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score--;
            }

            if(traffic_regulations!=0){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score = final_score[msg.sender].driver_score - traffic_regulations;
            }
        }

        if(final_score[msg.sender].driver_score<=100){
            if(60>=speed_traffic_highway || speed_traffic_highway<=120){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score++;
            }

            if(20>=speed_traffic_village || speed_traffic_village<=40){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score++;
            }

            if(headways_between_vehicles>=3){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score++;
            }

            if(acceleration>=6){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score++;
            }

            if(deceleration>=5){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score++;
            }

            if(overtaking_lane_changing<=10){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score++;
            }

            if(traffic_regulations==0){
                final_score[msg.sender].driver_score++;
            }
        }

        if(final_score[msg.sender].driver_score>0 && final_score[msg.sender].driver_score<=30){
            final_score[msg.sender].price = 1 ether;
        }

        if(final_score[msg.sender].driver_score>30 && final_score[msg.sender].driver_score<=50){
            final_score[msg.sender].price = 1 ether;
        }
        
        if(final_score[msg.sender].driver_score>50 && final_score[msg.sender].driver_score<70){
            final_score[msg.sender].price = 1 ether;
        }

        if(final_score[msg.sender].driver_score>70 && final_score[msg.sender].driver_score<=100){
            final_score[msg.sender].price = 1 ether;
        }

        console.log(final_score[msg.sender].price/1000000000000000000);
        console.log(final_score[msg.sender].driver_score);

        return (final_score[msg.sender].price, final_score[msg.sender].driver_score);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible for the smart contracts to fetch data from any website. because smart contract can not call the any API on the website Directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Chainlink Functions (https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions) to fetch any API data from Web2 to Smart Contracts in a decentralized manner.

You can refer to some examples at https://www.usechainlinkfunctions.com/